# How to organize SBTs with a lot of submodules?

Tags: sbt

I have a fairly large SBT project with many submodules. My `build.sbt` is quite large, and it is difficult to navigate. Is it possible to split the `build.sbt` into several smaller parts and have them "assembled" when running SBT jobs, similar to like it is done in Maven?

Suppose, I have something like:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(...)

lazy val lib1 = project.in(file(...))...
lazy val lib2 = project.in(file(...))...
lazy val lib3 = project.in(file(...))...
lazy val lib4 = project.in(file(...))...
lazy val foo1 = project.in(file(...))...
lazy val foo2 = project.in(file(...))...
lazy val bar1 = project.in(file(...))...
lazy val bar2 = project.in(file(...))...
lazy val bar3 = project.in(file(...))...
```

I want to have a common `build.sbt` which defines the common settings, and separate files for `lib`, `foo`, and `bar`.

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: One way is to have all your project with their own `build.sbt` configurations and then reference them all from your Root project. I have to go out for an hour or so but I will add a proper answer when I get back.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat each project in isolation and have it's own `build.sbt`. You can then reference the project using `ProjectRef`.

I have created an example project on [github](https://github.com/imarios/ToySbtMultiProject).

The great thing about using `ProjectRef` is that you can use the `url` construct to define dependencies to other remote project (e.g., other projects on github).

Comment: Looks promising. How would I tackle common settings all projects share?

Comment: That's a good question. I will update my answer with this, but I want to pass the idea by you first. One way to have common settings is add them as a plugin and then include the same plugin across all your project. Does that sound too complex? I will try to think of something else in the meanwhile ...